# How does caller method knows about which exceptions are being thrown by callee method?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I know in C# we do not require method to explicitly define the exceptions in method signature which it could throw. But, I would like to know how do we handle scenarios where caller method want to handle the possible exceptions thrown by callee method?

Let me be clear with my question.

Suppose there is a method defined in a DLL file as

```
public string DoSomething() 
{
  // This method do something and returns a string
}
```

Now as a caller I have knowledge of what method expects and what it returns as a result.But how do I know what are the possible exceptions thrown by this method.

In jave we have **throws** keyword. So If I was defining same method in java then I could have done something like below

```
public String doSomething() throws SomeException {
    // do something
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

This way caller of this method knows what exceptions need to be handled on their side.

How do we achieve this in C#, since C# doesn't have **throws** keyword in method signature?

One possible way would be to catch a generic **Exception** object. But again catching a generic exception is a horrible way to deal with exceptions.

Comment: You can always use Xml comments and list there all exceptions this mehtod throws. This way you'll be able to see that while typing because of intellisense

Comment: Even with Java, you don't just use Pokemon exception handling and call it a day. Either way, you need to understand which exceptions the method throws that the caller can *rationally* deal with, and that always requires human interpretation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Yeah but in java if callee method is re-throwing unified or custom exception (for all the exceptions which this method is dealing with), caller has to care about only that exception.
But in C# how do even caller knows what to handle since method signature doesn't give anything.
Apart from answers provided by m.rogalski and user3185569, is there any other way to achieve this? With all due respect but being a Java developer, it doesn't convince me to define all the exceptions thrown by my method in some XML file.

Comment: Like it or not, I believe the C# designers considered and rejected the idea of checked exceptions - I believe they're not without controversy even within the Java community. In C#, you consult the documentation. There's no programmatic mechanism. (And, of course, in both languages there are exceptions or runtime errors that will not be mentioned. I believe in Java these are Errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section in the XML documentation that is dedicated for this purpose:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="System.OutOfMemoryException"></exception>
/// <returns></returns>
public string DoSomething()
{
    // This method do something and returns a string
}
```

This allows the designer of the API to provide information to the client about what exceptions to expect from this method call. Like this:

[image]

You can get these XML lines generated by hitting `/` three times above the while the cursor is above the method.